# Múltiples bloques Catch en Java

Tags: java, excepciones

Me encuentro estudiando las Excepciones en Java y me encontré con la siguiente duda:

```
    System.out.println("A");
    try {
        System.out.println("B");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("C");
        throw new RuntimeException("1");  // Línea 7
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {        // Línea 8
        System.out.println("D");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("E");          // Línea 11
    }
```

En la línea 7 se lanza una excepción, la cual debería ser capturada por el bloque catch de la línea 8 (e imprimir "D"). Sin embargo esto no sucede, sino que la ejecución continúa directamente con el bloque finally.

El resultado del programa es **ABCE**, sin embargo no logró entender porque el bloque catch de la línea 8 es omitido.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme a esclarecer mi duda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-if-catch-block-contains-an-exception-in-java es en inglés, pero dice que si una excepción es echada dentro de un "catch" el programa termina (despues del finally).  Si queire capturar la excepción en el catch, tiene que usar otro "try".

```
  try {
        System.out.println("B");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      } 
  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       try {
           System.out.println("C");
           throw new RuntimeException("1");
           } 
       catch (RuntimeException e) {        // Línea 8
           System.out.println("D");
           } 
       }
   finally {
           System.out.println("E");          // Línea 11
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió para comprender mi error.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una diferencia entre el manejo de Excepciones con `catch` y `throw` entiéndanse estas dos palabras como:

> **catch** : Capturar.
>
> **throw** : Lanzar.

Cabe mencionar que un programa al entrar en un bloque `try` <sup>(probar)</sup> debe ir consecutivo un `catch` o en su defecto un `finally` <sup>(finalmente)</sup> . Todo esto es manejado como un bloque aparte de la ejecución del mismo.

### catch

Si el programa "captura" algún error con la ejecución del bloque `try`, este manda el error capturado hacia su bloque `catch` correspondiente, si no existiera la definición del error en alguno de los múltiples `catch` el programa continua con el bloque `finally` (si esta agregado) y finaliza el programa.

### throw

Permite Lazar una excepción en cualquier parte de la ejecución del programa sin depender de un bloque `try`, pero con el echo de que al "lanzarse" inmediatamente se detendrá el programa.

ejemplo:

```
try{
    if(i >= 10){
        throw new Exception("Mayor a 10"); //finaliza la ejecución
    }else{
        //code
    }
}
```